# R: Split Data Frame into Workbook/Worksheets WITH column names

Tags: r, dataframe, openxlsx

**Problem**: In the following example I am not able to get the column names from `DL_Import` into the many worksheets of the workbook `wb` and further into the many worksheets of the output Excel file `output.xlsx`...

**Context**: I have a data frame called `DL_Import` with close to 8,000 rows of data and 19 columns. I need to break this up into multiple worksheets for the saved xlsx file in order to process them separately downstream. I have completed this by doing the following:

```
DL_Split <- split(DL_Import,rep(1:500,each=1000)) 
chunk <- 1000 
numRows <- nrow(DL_Import) 
DL_row  <- rep(1:ceiling(numRows/chunk),each=chunk)[1:numRows] 
DL_Split <- split(DL_Import,DL_row) 
numSheets <- length(DL_Split) 

wb <- createWorkbook() 
for (i in 1:numSheets)
{
  addWorksheet(wb, i) 
  writeData(wb, i, DL_Split[i], startRow = 1, startCol = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = TRUE)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "output.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The workbook saves correctly with, in this case, 8 worksheets with the names "1", "2", ... "8" but **is missing the column titles in row 1 in each worksheets**.

**Question**: How can I ensure the column names from `DL_Import` gets propagated into each of the `wb` worksheets to ensure it's written to `output.xlsx` file?

Comment: why not explicitly write the column names in the first row? ie `writeData(wb, i, colnames(DL_Import), startRow = 1, startCol = 1)` then `writeData(wb, i, DL_Split[i], startRow = 2, startCol = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is that you were using `[` instead of `[[`, the difference between these two is fairly simple yet critical:

- `[` returns an object of the same class and can select one or more elements.
- `[[` returns only one element without coercing it to the type of the parent structure.

if you try this code, you'll find out that they're different:

```
class(DL_Split[1])
#> [1] "list"
class(DL_Split[[1]])
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

this is why `openxlsx::writeData` failed to get the column names and row names.

---

the corrected code should look like this

```
for (i in 1:numSheets)
{
  addWorksheet(wb, i) 
  writeData(wb, i, DL_Split[[i]], startRow = 1, startCol = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I added in the the line for "colnames," changed "StartCol = 1," but it only brings in the first column name (vs all). Thoughts?

Comment: try `as.data.frame(t(colnames(DL_Import)))` instead of colnames

Comment: Hm... That did something unexpected and wrote the column names on each worksheet as "V1, V2, V3, ... V19."

Comment: To follow up, if I run your command `as.data.frame(t(colnames(DL_Import)))` the Console outputs a line for the "V1, V2, V3, ..." and then the next line has the **actual** column names i'm looking for. I don't quite understand what thats about or how to get that second line under the V's

Comment: worked like a charm and thank you for pointing out the `[` vs `[[` difference that was very helpful to understand for the future. You are awesome and I hope you have a fantastic day!